# docker: Error response from daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: timeout"

Tags: docker

When I try to kill the Docker daemon by:

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: cf5fc4b0e5d1: Cannot kill container cf5fc4b0e5d152a7a89682d8835c40c59e9e0c2c41be4aae330ffeb8093814f2: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: timeout": unknown
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 590fab6b49a2: Cannot kill container 590fab6b49a2e3c832a99074a0679558a9f826d79e94bae7be4ca12c3a019b69: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: timeout": unknown
```

When I try to stop the Docker daemon by:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: cf5fc4b0e5d1: Cannot kill container cf5fc4b0e5d152a7a89682d8835c40c59e9e0c2c41be4aae330ffeb8093814f2: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: timeout": unknown
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 590fab6b49a2: Cannot kill container 590fab6b49a2e3c832a99074a0679558a9f826d79e94bae7be4ca12c3a019b69: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: timeout": unknown
```

What is the proper way to stop the Docker daemon?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the docker daemon?

Comment: no ...how to  restart the docker daemon

Comment: thanks its working...

Answer (score 26):

For macOS users: if you get the macOS equivalent:

`ERROR: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: connection refused`

You can restart Docker with the following:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

You need to stop the Docker daemon first and then start it.

To stop the Docker daemon:

`sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop`

To start the Docker daemon:

`sudo /etc/init.d/docker start`

This will reset Docker, after which all the commands should work properly.

If the above commands do not work, then just reboot:

`sudo reboot`

Comment: In my case I had to restart manually Docker, for some reason restarting the system didn't work.

Comment: Restarting the OS kernel to restart docker is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to run `systemctl status docker` and then either:

```
systemctl stop docker
systemctl start docker
```

Then verify whether docker daemon is up correctly or not with `systemctl status docker`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
killall Docker && open /Applications/Docker.app
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker never ends starting up.
Running `docker ps` helps me to fix issue